# JSONArray throws A JSONArray text must start with '[' at 1 [character 2 line 1] exception

Tags: java, json, exception

The following JSON Object (a variable named `json_object`) is composed of two values

- peripheral_devices
- peripheral_tests

both of which are arrays:

```
{
    "peripheral_devices": [
        {
            "_id": 1,
            "active": -1,
            "battery": "63",
            "bt_firmware_version": "btv1.7.777",
            "configured": 0,
            "connected": 0,
            "consumer_id": 22,
            "create_date": 1635807323224,
            "device_id": 72,
            "discovered": 0,
            "firmware_version": "v3.14",
            "hardware_version": "null",
            "icon": "icon_device_bp5",
            "last_connect_date": 1640023710420,
            "mac_address": "8C:DE:52:41:FC:57",
            "model": "BP5 41FC57",
            "name": "BP5",
            "other_id": "-1",
            "paired": -1,
            "type_id": 1,
            "update_date": 1635807323224,
            "user_id": 13
        },
        {
            "_id": 3,
            "active": -1,
            "battery": "90",
            "bt_firmware_version": "1.0.0",
            "configured": -1,
            "connected": 0,
            "consumer_id": 22,
            "create_date": 1635807323239,
            "device_id": 72,
            "discovered": 0,
            "firmware_version": "1.0.0",
            "hardware_version": "5.0.0",
            "icon": "icon_device_hs2s",
            "last_connect_date": 1640022147928,
            "mac_address": "00:4D:32:0C:B7:2C",
            "model": "HS2S 11070",
            "name": "HS2S",
            "other_id": "-1",
            "paired": -1,
            "type_id": 3,
            "update_date": 1635807323239,
            "user_id": 13
        }
    ],
    "peripheral_tests": [
        {
            "_id": 199,
            "consumer_id": 22,
            "create_date": 1640020949760,
            "end_date": 1640020949078,
            "mood_id": -1,
            "notes": "",
            "start_date": 1640020939533,
            "status_id": 1,
            "type_id": 2,
            "update_date": 0,
            "user_id": -99
        },
        {
            "_id": 198,
            "consumer_id": 22,
            "create_date": 1640020904183,
            "end_date": -1,
            "metric_bps": {,
            "mood_id": -1,
            "notes": "",
            "start_date": 1640020863742,
            "status_id": 1,
            "type_id": 1,
            "update_date": 0,
            "user_id": -99
        },
        {
            "_id": 197,
            "consumer_id": 22,
            "create_date": 1640020834664,
            "end_date": 1640020828741,
            "mood_id": -1,
            "notes": "",
            "start_date": 1640020822580,
            "status_id": 1,
            "type_id": 3,
            "update_date": 0,
            "user_id": -99
        }
    ]
}
```

and derived as follows:

```
JSONObject json_object = new JSONObject(post_data);
```

Using `org.json.JSONArray.JSONArray`:

```
JSONArray peripheral_devices = json_object.getJSONArray("peripheral_devices");
```

works as expected and a json array is parsed from `json_object`.  However, using the same technique to get the second array in the object does not:

```
JSONArray json_tests = new JSONArray("peripheral_tests");
```

throws exception:

```
A JSONArray text must start with '[' at 1 [character 2 line 1]
```

> Why?  What am I not understanding?

Comment: I think that your assumption, that `json_object` already is `typeof JSONObject` might be wrong... because one likely cannot access nested `JSONArray`, unless having a handle to the root `JSONObject`.... the `new` keyword NEVER is a getter.

Comment: @MartinZeitler - It's is and I have edited my post showing how it is derived.  Why would you think it's not?

Comment: @MartinZeitler - Thank you for spotting what I was overlooking - I am not actually using the json_object to get the array!   Oops   If you would please move to answer - I will give you credit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code

```java
JSONArray json_tests = new JSONArray("peripheral_tests");
```

Take string in the constructor which is the JSON data and `peripheral_tests` is not JSON array, to get peripheral_tests you need to get it from `json_object` like

```java
JSONArray peripheral_devices = json_object.getJSONArray("peripheral_tests");
```

Answer (score 0):

The input JSON is invalid, accoring to [JSON Lint](https://jsonlint.com) ...which may lead to unexpected results:

```
Error: Parse error on line 69:
..."metric_bps": {              ,               "mood_id": -1,
----------------------^
Expecting 'STRING', '}', got ','
```